# how to update specific value for every key using angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

i want to edit value when i click in this value, but when i do it it edits all value of row and not just to a specific key.
here is my code:

```
<table>

<tbody ng-repeat="(key,value) in row.entity.subData"><tr ng-repeat="item in value" >
<td   >
  <span ng-hide="row.entity.editing(item)" ng-click="row.entity.editItem(item)">{{item}}</span>
<button ng-show="row.entity.editing(item)">save</button>
  </td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

and for the javascript code :

```
row.entity.editItem = function (item) {
    row.entity.editing=function (item) {
    return true; 
  }
}
```

when i click in value i want this value be a button ,but the result return all values to button

Comment: please show me all of your controller code

Comment: defining and re-defining a method in response to an event is a bad practice. it would be much better to create a model property, say `showButton`, and have your `editItem` method set the property to the Boolean value required (`showButton` would be an array corresponding to your `<tr>`s). Then simply initialize the `showButton` array elements to false and use `showButton[$index]` in your `ng-show` and `ng-hide`.

Comment: this is my plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/m5CAzzuRjtBk9FlLPB7i?p=preview

Comment: the code html is in expandableRowTemplate.html and the javascript is in app.js line 84

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks a lot can you give me an example

Comment: The answer provided by unmeat puts you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

So from the code you supplied - you have one object: row.entity.**subData**, with values containing even arrays of **items**.

I'm assuming your goal is to make a single click affect a single cell (**item**) or row (**subData**).

However, you are changing the key "row.entity.*editing*" to true whenever you click on a cell. There is only 1 reference to this variable - and therefore every single item in your ng-repeat will both change and be affected by the click.

You need to change a variable in each individual row.entity.**subData[key]**, rather than row.entity.*.

To fix this:
I'd recommend you to change your data structure.
You should nest objects inside of an array with two values:

```
row.entity.subData = [{  isShown:true,  data: [...] }, ...]
```

The data key is what you originally had in the array.

The isShown key determines the ng-if conditional.

```html
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="object in row.entity.subData">
  
    <!-- if you are hiding the whole row, you click logic should exist on the row level-->
    <!-- depending on your dataset size, it is a better practice to use ng-if in a table -->
    
    <tr ng-if="object.isShown" 
        ng-click="object.isShown = !object.isShown" 
        ng-repeat="item in object.data" >
      <td >
        <span>
             {{item}}
        </span>
      <!-- For this save button, you'd have to clarify with me what  -->
      <!-- it is you wish to accomplish after clicking it,  -->
      <!-- do you want to change the cell or the row -->
          <button ng-show="object.isShown" ng-click="save(object)">
              save
          </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I do it but its edit all row not just one value for every attribute

Answer (score 0):

For showing or hiding a specific item in an ng-repeat i suggest to format your data object like this :

```
angular.foreach(data, function(value){
     value.isVisible=false;
};
```

Then you can show or hide your button for that item you want to edit by changing the value of isVisible to what you want .

```
<table>
    <tbody><tr ng-repeat="item in data" >
    <td>
      <span ng-hide="!item.isVisible" ng-click="row.editItem(item)">{{item}}</span>
    <button ng-show="item.isVisible">save</button>
      </td>
    </tr></tbody></table>
```

I think i was helpful good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot For row.editItem(item) function i put item.isVisible=true;  but its not applicated

Comment: Use debugger inside your function to locate why didn't applicate

Answer (score 0):

as a solution that i found for this

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {

  
   $scope.items = [{
        name: "item #1",
        id:4
        
    }
    ];

    $scope.editItem = function (value,$index) {
         if($index==0){
         $scope.editing =function ($index) {
       if($index==0){
       return true;
       }
        }
        $scope.backup = angular.copy(value);
         }
         if($index==1){
         $scope.editing =function ($index) {
       if($index==1){
       return true;
       }
        }
        $scope.backup = angular.copy(value);
         }
        
    }

    $scope.doneEditing = function (value,$index) {
    if($index==0){
         $scope.editing =function ($index) {
       if($index==0){
       return false;
       }
        }
        delete $scope.backup;
         }
         if($index==1){
         $scope.editing =function ($index) {
       if($index==1){
       return false;
       }
        }
        delete $scope.backup;
         }
       
    };
    $scope.Cancel = function (value,$index) {
     if($index==0){
         $scope.editing =function ($index) {
       if($index==0){
       return false;
       }
        }
        this.value = angular.copy($scope.backup);
        delete $scope.backup;
         }
         if($index==1){
         $scope.editing =function ($index) {
       if($index==1){
       return false;
       }
        }
         this.value = angular.copy($scope.backup);
        delete $scope.backup;         }
       
    };
  
}
```

```css
.container {
    margin-top:10px;
    font-family:arial;
}
input:focus {
    //change more attributes, if you want.
}
input {
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
}
.container header {
    padding-bottom:20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
ul, input, .container {
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
        <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in items[0]">
           <td>{{key}} </td>
           <td>
                <span  ng-hide="editing($index)"  > {{value}} <button  ng-click="editItem(value,$index)">Edit</button></span>
                <input ng-show="editing($index)" ng-model="value"  autofocus />
                <button ng-show="editing($index)" ng-click="doneEditing(value,$index)">Save</button>
                 <button ng-show="editing($index)" ng-click="Cancel(value,$index)">Cancel</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
         
        </table>
   
</div>
```